# How does `pv` know the destination disk's size?

Tags: linux

I recently zeroed a drive with the following command:

```
# pv /dev/zero > /dev/sdd
```

Looking at the throughput and time remaining according to `pv`, it correctly estimated/calculated/knew the size of the disk - 120GB - right from the start of the operation.

My question is, how did `pv` know this, when its output is being redirected this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`man 1 pv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pv.1.html):

> Note that if the input size cannot be calculated, and the output is a block device, then the size of the block device will be used and `pv` will automatically stop at that size as if `-S` had been given.

This "as if `-S`" is to avoid "no space left on device" and to exit successfully.

---

If you wonder how it is that `pv` can know the size of its stdout, then the answer is:

It's not the case `pv` streams to some fifo and then the shell reads the fifo and writes to `/dev/sdd`. What happens is the shell makes the `pv`'s file descriptor 1 point to `/dev/sdd` from the very beginning, so the process can detect it is a block device, query about its size etc.

Comment: Ah, I see, awesome! I thought the shell always created a FIFO for redirections/pipes. Makes sense. Thanks!